# database inside onReceive

Tags: android, database, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a service which does some work, when done, it send a broadcast. In activity the receiver is registered and pick up the broadcast in its onReceive. Now I need to select data from database and show them inside listview. But I dont want to do the database select on ui thread because that can be expensive operation, I want to open async task, but thats agains the lifecycle of receiver. What other solution do I have ? To open service ? Yes I can do the database operation in new service but how can I then deliver the data to the views from service ? Updating views from service is for sure something I dont want to do. I am in a kind of deathlock right now.

Thanks for any ideas

edit 1: this is the explanation from android documentation why you cannot use AsyncTask in onReceive and why the answers are invalid

> Receiver Lifecycle
>        A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>        This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>        In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead
>   use the NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

edit 2: The answers led me to a solution, to create a handler in the activity and pass it to the receiver, in its onReceive just post message to the handler and then inside the handler open the async task and do the database stuff. Not sure though if this is a good one.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the asynctask?

Comment: onReceive lives only until you return, then the system is free to kill its process, so if i open async task from onReceive I cannot be sure that system wont kill it before it is done.

Comment: you can use a ContentObserver, coupled with registerContentObserver, a unique Uri, and a notifyChange(Uri, null) in your service

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to create an `Interface` that returns data to the `Activity` where you can fill the `ListView`. I had just created a demo using `AsyncTask` in which I do the database operations in the `AsyncTask` and the send the data to `Activity` using an `Interface` and update the UI. So, you can just try to replace `AsyncTask` with `Service` and perform your own action. [`Here is a sample demo source for Database Operation in AsyncTask and returning its content to Activity`](https://github.com/lalit3686/SqliteLoaderDemo).

Comment: the problem is not to do database operation in async task and then update the list view, the problem is that I cannot open async task inside onReceive